# Is this set measure dense?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is this set measure dense? Let $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure. Let $\{r_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an enumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$. Let $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ Consider the set $$A=\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(r_k-\frac{\epsilon}{2^k},r_k+\frac{\epsilon}{2^k})$$

Then for any interval $I \subset [0,1]$, $0<\mu(I \cap A)$? How do I show this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $I$ be a non-empty open interval. Find $k$ with $r_k\in I$. Then $I\cap (r_k-\frac{\epsilon}{2^k},r_k+\frac{\epsilon}{2^k})$ is a non-empty interval, hence has positive measure. But said interval is contained in $A\cap I$, hence $A\cap I$ has positive measure too.